# Laravel: PHPUnit and interacting with JavaScript

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have a very simple popup dialog that is driven by JavaScript in my Laravel app. Essentially, on click, a class is added to the popup `div` that uses a CSS transition to change its opacity from 0 to 1.

Here's my test:

```
public function testCantFindCodePopup()
{
  $customer = $this->createCustomer();
  $this->fillOutEmailAndDob($customer);

  $this->visit('/product-codes/new')
       ->dontSee("Still can't find your code?");
  $this->click('Can\'t find your code?');
         sleep(0.5);
  $this->see("Call customer service");
}
```

The transition takes 300ms, so I thought `sleep`ing for 500ms would solve the issue, but no dice.

And actually, the test fails on the `dontSee("Still can't find your code?")` part, even though that text is inside of the popup, which has `display: none` set on it on load.

Am I doing something wrong, or is PHPUnit not aware of CSS and JavaScript like [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) is (because it runs in a headless browser).

If I can't use PHPUnit for this type of integration test, is there something similar that I *can* use? Note that I have ~70 other tests in PHPUnit, so whatever other tool there is, it can't be a wholesale replacement; ideally it'd exist alongside my PHPUnit tests.

### Edit

Relevant part of the blade template:

```
<div class="form-control">
          <label for="product-code">Enter Your{{$second}}Code</label>
          <input type="text" id="product-code" name="product-code" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <span class="label-explanation js__popup-toggle">Can't find your code?
          <div class='popup'>
            <span class="popup__close">&times;</span>
            <img src="/assets/images/find-code-pop-up.png" alt="[alt text]" />
            <p class="popup__cannot-find">Still can't find your code?<br/> Call customer service at xxx-xxx-xxxx.</p>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.popup
  width 300px
  position absolute
  left 35%
  bottom 0
  transition width 0.3s, height 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, transform 0.45s
  opacity 0
  background rgba(255,255,255,0.9)
  color $brand-primary-dark
  text-align center
  transform scale(0)
  p
    font-size 16px
    text-transform none
    line-height 1.15
  &.js__display
    height auto
    opacity 1
    transform scale(1)
    z-index 9999

.popup__close
  font-size 20px
  position absolute
  top 0
  right 5px
  transition font-size 0.3s
  &:hover
    font-size 24px
```

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. In this case, PHPUnit is not aware of CSS and JavaScript. I was checking Laravel Testing module source code (which extends PHPUnit functionality) and it just uses a crawler. So, it doesn't run any client-side script. Actually, it doesn't even render the page.

Comment: BTW, I didn't use it yet, but you may give a try to [phpunit-spiderling](https://github.com/OpenBuildings/phpunit-spiderling).

Comment: @GustavoStraube Both of these are great answers. Submit them together as an answer, and I'll mark them correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. In this case, PHPUnit is not aware of CSS and JavaScript. I was checking Laravel Testing module source code (which extends PHPUnit functionality) and it just uses a crawler. So, it doesn't run any client-side script. Actually, it doesn't even render the page.

I didn't use it yet, but you may give a try to [phpunit-spiderling](https://github.com/OpenBuildings/phpunit-spiderling).

Answer (score 2):

I see this is a very old question, but just for documentations sake:

If you would like to test with browser functionality you can have a look at Laravel Dusk:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/dusk

Dusk uses a Chrome driver to visit your project on your local machine for example. So it will execute the javascript too in case you are using a framework like Vue.js for example.

This is what a test looks like:

```
public function test_careers_page_shows_vacancies()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $career = \App\Career::first();
        $browser->visit("/careers")
                ->assertSee("Join our team!")
                ->pause(1000) // Pause for a second
                ->waitForText("Careers loaded") // Or wait for text
                ->assertSee($career->title);
    });
}
```

Note that Dusk will use your `local` environment unlike phpunit which might use a `testing` environment. For example, I use an sqlite environment for phpunit. But Dusk browses to "http://myproject.test/" which uses a different database. You can solve this by setting up a testing database on you local machine.

Comment: It's better to provide more information in answer instead of just post the link.